# Run command on brightness change

Tags: brightness, dbus, gconf

as the brightness selected doesn't change my effective brightness, but xbacklight does, I just wanted to sync them.

So, I would like to run xbacklight on login, in order so adjust to the saved state, and also run xbacklight with the current selected brightness, whenever it changes.

Is there a way?

Thank you.